# Asp.net : How to write a regular expression that validates strings of two lengths?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need to validate strings(only digits) that have the length of 7 OR 10 . `ValidationExpression="^\d{10}$"`
this piece of code accept strings with length of 10 digits, but i also want to include strings length of 7 digits.
if i use `ValidationExpression="^\d{7,10}$"` , i can enter digits with the length of 7 or 10,   but i also can enter 8 and 9 digits witch is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an OR: `"^(\d{7}|\d{10})$"`